# Can we display a mix of horizontal and vertical words in one sheet in tableau word cloud?

Tags: tableau-api

So we can create a word cloud in tableau but when we create it all the words are always horizontal, like ->

[image: Horizontal words in word cloud]

I want to show them in a mixed manner, horizontal and vertical together, kind of like->
[image: outcome word cloud]

I have tried to make changes and referred this url from tableau community.

https://community.tableau.com/thread/136977

Here they say the best option is to make two separate sheets one with all horizontal words and one with all vertical words and then arrange them next to each other, that is on one sheet you can either have all vertical words or all horizontal words, that's not the best solution. I want them to be on one sheet with a mixed pattern of vertical and horizontal words.

Is this possible in tableau?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy answer is: No!
At least not in a way that you have in mind. As you mentioned, you can change the orientation of the whole cloud or you create 2 clouds on a dual axis, but it will not create dense cloud like in your example. It will rather have gaps and words overlapping each other.
Even if you go with what they mention in one of the comments, to define manual coordinates, you will essentially create the cloud by yourself and lay everything out manually. In case the size of a word changes, you would probably have to change most of the coordinates again.

If you want a word cloud in your dashboard, you could create it externally and embed it in your dashboard. Obviously you wouldn't have the Tableau features, like filtering and highlighting, but that would be the closest you can get to a nice looking cloud in Tableau.